# Enviar e-mail para criação de compromisso no Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-calendar

Tenho uma aplicação C# ASP.NET MVC, em que o usuário pode agendar um compromisso. Nessa aplicação ele escolhe um texto para o compromisso, uma Data para acontecer e escolhe também, quanto antes ele quer ser avisado do compromisso, que gerá um datetime para essa data do lembrete.

O próximo passo, seria eu criar uma "ferramenta" que ficasse consultado a cada 5 minutos se há lembretes a serem enviados para o e-mail do usuário. Pelo que eu li, eu teria que criar um bat no servidor para fazer esse trabalho.

A outra opção seria, na criação do compromisso, enviar um e-mail para o usuário, para que esse e-mail gerasse uma agenda automática para o usuário na agenda Google, como acontece hoje com as cias aéreas como TAM e AZUL. (Todos os usuários possuem e-mail Google).

Alguém sabe como funciona esses e-mails que geram compromissos na agenda Google? O que me sugerem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um evento que possa ser recriado em diversos calendários como Google e Apple Calendar, pode utilizar arquivos iCalendar (*.ics).

Existe o [iCal.NET, uma biblioteca .NET de código aberto](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) para criação e manipulação de arquivos nesse padrão. Está disponível como [pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net), é só executar

```
Install-Package Ical.Net
```

no Package Manager do Visual Studio.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.Subject = "Seu compromisso";
message.Body = "Adicione ao seu calendário!";
message.To.Add("nome@exemplo.com.br");
message.From = new MailAddress("fulano@tal.com.br", "Fulano de Tal");

// criação do evento
calendar.Events.Add(new Event {
    Class = "PUBLIC",
    Summary = "Seu evento",
    Created = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Now),
    Description = res.Details,
    Start = new CalDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now)),
    End = new CalDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(5))),
    Sequence = 0,
    Uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
  });

var serializer = new CalendarSerializer(new SerializationContext());
var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
var bytesCalendar = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedCalendar);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytesCalendar);
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(ms, "evento.ics", "text/calendar");
message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

No exemplo acima vê como utilizar essa biblioteca para gerar o arquivo iCalendar, criar um e-mail e anexá-lo.

O arquivo *.ics gerado segue esse padrão (retirado [daqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)):

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe:MAILTO:john.doe@example.com
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Reitero que o grande ganho em utilizar esse tipo de arquivo é que é aceito em muitos provedores. Yahoo, Apple, Google e Microsoft aceitam esse padrão.

Veja como o Outlook Web trata quando há um *.ics anexado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- [Documentação da biblioteca iCal.NET](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/wiki)
- [iCalendar Resources, Specifications and Tools](https://icalendar.org)
- [RFC 5545 (Internet calendaring and scheduling core object specification)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @vnbrs! Me diga uma coisa, quando a pessoa receber esse e-mail, ela será solicitada a inserir esse compromisso na agenda? ou ao já será incluído automaticamente?

Comment: Isso é responsabilidade do cliente de e-mail. Do meu conhecimento, o Mail do Windows 10 e o Outlook Web fazem uma solicitação para inserir.

Comment: Vou fazer uns testes, gerando um arquivo desse e envia-lo para o meu e-mail gmail para ver o comportamento. Muito obrigado!